# Python parser using Regex for a course catalog

Tags: python, regex, parsing, python-re

I've been trying to develop a type of parser for old course catalogs and have an idea of what I want to do but cannot figure it out.  Basically, the premise is that I want to parse and find the course abbreviations, so Computer Science would be abbreviated as "(CSC)."  Next, I would need to find the course numbers, course title, and course units.  My regex pattern for these are simple:

```
course_abbrev = re.compile('\([A-Z]{3}\)')
course_num = re.compile('[0-9]{3},?')
course_title = re.compile('.+?(?=I )')
course_units = re.compile('\d')
```

The format of the catalogs all differ slightly, but they are relatively as followed:

```
"""
Computer Science (CSC)  
Chairman: ...
201 Introduction to Computing I, 3
(Information of the course)...

220 Another Comp Class I, 3
(Information)... 
...  
...
...

Dental Hygiene (DHY)
Chairman: ...
101...
"""
```

The text of the catalog is somewhat jumbled because it is being read via PyPDF2 since the catalogs are in PDF format but as such I am reading a page at a time of information. What would an efficient method be to go about finding the abbreviations, finding the number after that abbreviation, to then find the title after that number, and then the course unit.  The re module has ways to list all of these patterns (re.findall()) or search for one of them (re.search()) but I am unsure how to go about finding one, storing it, and then finding a different regex pattern from there, storing it, etc.
EDIT: The input looks like this thanks to PyPDF2, with pages being broken up and separating chunks of information:

```
COMPUTER SCIENCE (CSC) 
CHAIRMAN: Professor Name (Computer Science 
and Experimental Statistics) 
201 Introduction 
to Computing I and II, 3 
Algorithms, programs, and computers. Basic 
ming and program structure, data representation, 
zation and characteristics of computers. Computer 
tion of other stuff... 
(Lee. 3). Staff 220 Computers in Society 
II, 3 History, operation, application, and 
social significance of 
computers. Emphasis on the role of the computer in 
ciety with respect to more information and dan
gers. (Lee. 3) Carrano
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you show the exact input and output? It's nice that you've thought about it and shown some attempt here, but this leaves a bit too much to the imagination so it's hard to write an answer. I appreciate the clarification!

Comment: You might use a pattern like this, but you need the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) for that. 
`(?:^.* \(([A-Z]{3})\).*|\G(?!^))(?:\r?\n(?!\d{3} |.* \([A-Z]{3}\)[^\S\r\n]*$).*)*\r?\n(\d{3}) (.*?) I, (\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/Y9K6hY/1/

Comment: Thanks! So the input would be the name of the course, followed by the course abbreviation, some unnecessary information, followed by a list of the classes starting with their class number, the title, an I to indicate whether or not it is the first class or the secondary (for example, Calculus I or Calculus II) and then the unit credit.  Following that is a description of the class but unnecessary information.  In the end, I would like a list of lists that matches: `[CSC, 201, Introduction to Computing, 3], [CSC, 220, Another Comp, 3], ...]`

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make use of the `\G` anchor to get iterative matches using the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/).

While looping the matches, you can create a temporary list starting by adding the first group only when it is not None

Then add all other subsequent groups to it, and finally add the temporary list to the results list.

```
(?:^.* \(([A-Z]{3})\).*|\G(?!^))(?:\r?\n(?!\d{3} |.* \([A-Z]{3}\)[^\S\r\n]*$).*)*\r?\n(\d{3}) (.*?) I, (\d+)
```

*Explanation*

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `^.* \(([A-Z]{3})\).*` Start of string and capture in group 1 three times an uppercase char A-Z
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the positive at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close group
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n(?!` Match a newline and assert that the string does not contain
  - `\d{3}`  Match 3 digits and space
  - `|` OR
  - `.* \([A-Z]{3}\)[^\S\r\n]*$).*` Match 3 uppercase chars A-Z at the end of the string
- `)*` Close group and repeat that 0 or more times
- `\r?\n` Match a newline
- `(\d{3}) (.*?) I, (\d+)` Match in 3 groups: 3 digits all before the capital `I` and 1+ digits after the `I` and a comma and space

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y9K6hY/1/) and a [Python demo](https://tio.run/##zZLBitswEIbveoqp6UHjdc16cwuEsHhhN1D2klMbJcU4siOIR0aSoUu3z57KSpxkcWiv1Uma@eb/R8O0b26naXI4qKbVxoGRtfzJWFs4Jw3BDEzE59NNGoPgfPX45fv61@Q3Ckzjd/HM5582iD4vzFyQf4mtz8J7oAdY4GojlsIIWseffR3GRzqwCDyN5wiLBHzgDiPGnLTuh3XGe/Mo103b@U5gWSpJpQSeL3MUFDG4OlG@K5RpCppCmqaj7MN9BgtyRm@70ilN4DQchRXVvfVkVMIXVGmvGHBdgdtJKHVnrMTgMPZ4uIdH0p4zQRvyfWHtv8V7ORgRffBm9HZsFH2S5Io9vLzVfmp@aE8v3/CG4N/Hlv3vY4uQMf8sd9L2i9pvblop2iq/MPy0wQkM@4TMSNvtXc@u1qxSxrpno7vWv181Sca8OgS9165JjjdQBJK6RprCSX4yS8C6wrhZhtPQoaqOcFr3cjxDUBb8p4Ls9PyJD44fC1iAnGzar8q6vsELvA65vrdA@976pkxBteRZAntJ/ErMckS8eJ5LZpfrHWTn/GCZFm0raXutxIcCxICfpjeQQyWy1ihy/JT2Xzkc/gA)

*Example code*

```
import regex

pattern = r"(?:^.* \(([A-Z]{3})\).*|\G(?!^))(?:\r?\n(?!\d{3} |.* \([A-Z]{3}\)[^\S\r\n]*$).*)*\r?\n(\d{3}) (.*?) I, (\d+)"

test_str = ("Computer Science (CSC)\n"
            "Chairman: ...\n"
            "201 Introduction to Computing I, 3\n"
            "(Information of the course)...\n\n"
            "220 Another Comp Class I, 3\n"
            "(Information)... \n"
            "...  \n"
            "...\n"
            "...\n\n"
            "Dental Hygiene (DHY)  \n"
            "Chairman: ...\n"
            "101 Introduction to Computing I, 3\n"
            "(Information of the course)...\n\n"
            "220 Another Comp Class I, 3\n"
            "(Information)... ")

matches = regex.finditer(pattern, test_str)
results = []
firstGroup = None

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    if match.group(1) is not None:
        firstGroup = match.group(1)

    tempList = [firstGroup]
    for groupNum in range(1, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        tempList.append(match.group(groupNum))
    results.append(tempList)
print(results)
```

*Output*

```
[['CSC', '201', 'Introduction to Computing', '3'], ['CSC', '220', 'Another Comp Class', '3'], ['CSC', '101', 'Introduction to Computing', '3'], ['CSC', '220', 'Another Comp Class', '3']]
```

Comment: This is awesome but the problem is that the input is not as clean as I want it to be.  I added an edit to show how the input actually looks like and it's a jumble of information.  Also it is separated by pages read and if the page cuts off the information midway then it won't count.  I was thinking this might work if I simply concatenate all of the pages into a large string variable.

Comment: @CMoua But if the information is not structured as in the example but is a jumble of information, which parts are always the same and which can differ? Does this part `Computer Science (CSC)` always start on a new line? Does this part `201 Introduction to Computing I, 3` always start on a new line and is the `I, 3` always present? What is the logic to get the different parts of the data?

Comment: I believe the information only gets cutoff if it is too long, such as the descriptions of the class.  The names of the course followed by the abbreviation is not always at the start of a newline, the class numbers followed by the titles are present but not always on a newline and the `I, 3` is present.